# Firefox 3.5 color correction hack?

Tags: html, css, firefox, png, firefox3.5

After finally getting down to upgrading to FF 3.5, I noticed that some of my web pages have color problems. Specifically, say I have a PNG image with a color in it which is meant to be the same as the body's background color but when it is rendered it comes out as lighter than it should be on Windows.

On Mac I'm not seeing this issue, and nor am I seeing it on FF3.0 - Windows or otherwise.

Is there some hack I can add to my code to make FF not color correct the PNG?

Comment: The solution I need is a global one. I can't make everyone disable that option.

Comment: Can you check what profile your images are using?  If your images use ICC v4 you may be experiencing this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488800

Try forcing an image to use ICC v2 and see if you still see the issues.

Comment: I have noticed the same with jpg images, white turns to a light shade of blue, etc. But only in some images...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by running all the PNGs through pngcrush and remove all traces of color profiles and such.

```
pngcrush -rem gAMA -rem cHRM -rem iCCP -rem sRGB in.png out.png
```

Answer (score 7):

Check your [image tagging](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/color-correction/). Specifically I think you can change FF3.5's behaviour in this regard by editing the `gfx.color_management.mode` property (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox))

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely due to the decision by Firefox to use ICC color profiles by default in Firefox 3.5: [See this post on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox)

You can change this in FF3.5 by entering 'about:config' in the address bar, then searching for the parameter: gfx.color_management.mode and setting it to '0' (the default in FF3.0).

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3.5 now [supports ICC profiles](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/color-correction/) per default. That means that you can control the color output of Firefox via your OS settings.
Propably, your ICC profile is not correct and you have to adapt it in your OS. It's not Firefox i think. You don't need a hack for this.

It's a client problem, as I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the header jpg of my site. I tried to save it again in Photoshop (this time with **ICC profile uncheked while saving**). Results: files smaller, colors match.
Thanks!

Comment: Life saver, this fixed our problems.

Answer (score 0):

This comment was very helpful for me:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/color-correction/#comment-1490

I just ran

```
jpegtran -optimize -outfile out.jpg in.jpg
```

on all of my JPEGs and everything looks like it did before installing 3.5.

Comment: Since the problem has already been solved, I guess this is more just for future reference for anyone else running into this problem who's using JPEGs and not PNGs..

Answer (score 0):

You can save your images with no profile data (for example if you have a JPG and save it in an old photo editor without that feature) then Firefox doesn't alter it.  I have to say, that is a SUPER obnoxious feature.  They should have a global on/off switch that you can embed into the HTML code to deal with it.  BLah.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old thread, just wanted to update. I ran into this very problem with IE9 & FF 17. The problem for me was in the color profile used in Photoshop. This post solved my problem http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/

Hope this helps someone out there.
Happy web building!

Answer (score -3):

Try saving images for web (if you're using photoshop), because I guess it's different color scale.