# Image color differences in different browsers. (Firefox, Chrome, IE)

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-7, firefox3.5

Oi!

I have a question regarding the differences in how images are being rendered inside of Firefox then in Internet Explorer. Firefox version is 3.5.19 and Internet Explorer version is MSIE 7.0.

[Firefox http://www.wmclan.net/i/images/15877834356924635314.png](http://www.wmclan.net/i/images/15877834356924635314.png)
[Internet Explorer http://www.wmclan.net/i/images/95502460007153569229.png](http://www.wmclan.net/i/images/95502460007153569229.png)

I was thinking a possible solution from [Firefox 3.5 color correction hack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108476/firefox-3-5-color-correction-hack) but is there a better way of doing that instead of running every single image through that process? How do I make it so that the images have the same background color as the background... I selected the color from the background with photoshop's color picker and used the same color code for each the image and the background image. This works fine with IE and also Chrome.. have not tested on other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the gamma data that is added to the images. I thinks this is only a mac issue. The image is altered based on the gamma data, and doesn't match the css color values.

The solution you found is the only way to disable this "feature".

If you don't like the command line there is also easy drag and drop tool called PngThing.app for mac. I'm not using windows, so you'll have to google for that.

Comment: That was actually Firefox on Windows XP. What a terrible "feature". Thanks i'll just use the command on my linux box.