# Background image color changes firefox/chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, browser

I have a very strange from when testing a website on Chrome.

The CSS is exactly the same but appears different. Plus tested on the same monitor.

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Chrome

[image]

You can see from the Chrome print screen the background image I am using for the knives/forks, its the background color of this image which changes.

Comment: My Firefox is displaying it like your Chrome screenshot - background color changed. __EDIT:__ Upon copying the two into photoshop, it displays similarly. __EDIT 2:__ Interesting.. It only does so after copying directly from firefox. If I download the image, and then copy it, it has the same background color...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The background image at http://www.cater-shawrecruitment.co.uk/webapp/templates/default/images/bgpage.jpg has an embedded colour profile, which different browsers will interpret differently.  You'll need to re-render the image without the embedded colour profile.

This is probably caused by using photoshop to simply 'Save' the JPG, rather than 'Save for web'ing.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, your image has a color profile applied, and thus is being rendered differently in Chrome and Firefox, which only the former of these two will actually respect it. Reading off of [Chris Coiyer's article on web color profiles](http://css-tricks.com/567-color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/), you can fix the problem by doing as follows:

> If you "**Save As...**" from the file menu, you will have the **opportunity to save your color profile** along with the image. If you "**Save for Web & Devices...**" the "sRGB" (best for the web) color profile will be automatically applied (in CS3 anyway).

Answer (score 0):

this is something to do with colorprofiles.

this might help - [Image color differences in different browsers. (Firefox, Chrome, IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141145/image-color-differences-in-different-browsers-firefox-chrome-ie)

and this

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143

check your colorprofiles in photoshop (cmd+shift+k) and try to recreate the image. should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the image to be png it will be the same color. The reason is in the link of @Nightfirecat and in @graphicdivine 's answer.