# Weird anomaly of a graphic being with different color on one computer, but ok in another

Tags: image, rendering, photoshop

Me and my colleague are facing a weird anomaly of one little graphic being purple in his computer and blue in mine. The file itself seems to okay and we have re-created it from PSD several times.

You would say that, the problem is local in his computer. However, our computers are fairly similar and there has never been this issue before. Also, if he checks the source-file its ok, meaning blue. His computer had a fresh install of Win7 and clean photoshop.

What could be the problem and what can we try to solve it?

**More information:**

He is using FF5. The image is in PNG format. There are no js related scripts, to alter any of the images.

- [Direct link](http://kopli.pri.ee/area52cms/demo/cp/skins/skin_1/images/current_menu_active3.png)
- [Live example](http://kopli.pri.ee/area52cms/demo/cp/)

*(In the image we are talking about the little arrow, that is purple in one image)*

**From my point of view:**

[image: My arrow]

**From his point of view:**

[image: His arrow]

**NOTE:** I personally think the issue is local in his computer. But he of course doesn't accept this answer. So if it is local, then somebody could explain, how does it happen.

Comment: Are you using different browsers?

Comment: Are you using FF5 as well? Your live example does not look like the screenshots.

Comment: Just to be sure: He does not have a cached version if an image? Is it the PNG on the website or already in the PSD?

Comment: I'm using FF3, the live example is not crossbrowser yet -- you must use FF3+.
I thought my browser is irrelevant, because in all other computers I've checked, its okay.
Cleared out all possible caches, even thought our browsers don't cache for the sake of the development. Its only the PNG, PSD has always been okay. Also the preview, that was produced from the same PSD, with the same program in PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could be due to [gamma correction and color correction](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GammaCorrectionAndColorCorrectionPNGIsStillTooHard.aspx) for PNGs. Ran into a similar issue myself with PNGs a couple weeks ago. A PNG would display with the correct colors in one browser, and with different colors in another browser on the same computer.

See this stackoverflow question as well for more info: [Firefox 3.5 color correction hack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108476/firefox-3-5-color-correction-hack)

**EDIT**
I definitely think this is a color correction issue, take a look at the images in two different browsers (chrome 13 and firefox5) on my machine. The image in Firefox is displaying with different colors than the one in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Yes yes, but the source file in his computer and browser is okay, but not in the site.

Comment: @Kalle I think you should use pngcrush on the image as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108476/firefox-3-5-color-correction-hack. I wish I had another answer, but I can't see how this isn't a color correction issue with the browser.

Comment: If the problem would be in the browser, then viewing the source file should result the same. But the graphic turns purple, only when used on the site.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing over here. Both look purple in FF5. Both look blue in Chrome.

Comment: Yes thanks, the issue was in color correction. Not sure what my designer did, but he said to give you the accept. So thanks :)

Comment: Cool, glad you got it figured out. =]

Answer (score 0):

Check the color settings on your monitors. If you're using different [color temperature](http://www.3drender.com/glossary/colortemp.htm) (Kelvin) settings, or your RGB settings are non-default and different, or if your monitors are different makes/vintages, you might see things display in "different" colors.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but if it's a color correction problem, then the entire bar would be purple, not just the arrow part.

Comment: All graphics for this site have been produced from the same computer, with the same program. Both computers are with calibrated monitors.

Comment: Well actually, that blue bar's gradient is done with css and the arrow is png. But the general point remains.