# Disable color correction in Firefox programatically per image?

Tags: firefox, colors, png, html5-canvas, color-profile

this question is in close relation to [Firefox 3.5 color correction hack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108476/firefox-3-5-color-correction-hack)

The situation I have is that there's a canvas game of mine, and the images that are used in it carry additional information about their shape, connection points etc. This information is stored in the PNG image itself, using meaningful colours (eg RGB(255,255,0) for connection point).

Loading element and painting on the canvas creates Image object, img.src is set, and in img.load function I preprocess image data reading the sensitive information (and removing sensitive pixels from the image data before painting to canvas).

The problem: In FF, the pixel which was supposed to be 255,255,0 is actually 255,254,0. I don't have problems with FF color correction (I don't care if the displayed image has right colors, or slightly modified), but I'd expect that getting image data gives me uncorrected data. I'm looking for a solution which would *not involve changing images on the server*. Is there some way? Eg.
    img.setColorProfile(), or
    img.disableColorCorrection(), or
    img.getImageData(disableColorCorrection) or img.getImageData(colorProfile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might have do more with image loading than image drawing.

I think the proper solution is to strip out color profile information from the images (which you seem to want to aovid). If possible server another image resources for Firefox if you cannot need to have the original data intact.

http://f6design.com/journal/2006/12/01/fixing-png-gamma/

Also, you could decode PNG immages in pure Javascript if the server is co-operate and allows CORS and AJAX loading of the images. You decode the image in Javascript using png.js and create a source `<canvas>` from the image data (instead of `<img>`). This way it's *you* in the control what RGB values comes out from each PNG pixel.

https://github.com/devongovett/png.js

Comment: Well, this sucks. I'll wait for other answers before I accept this, although I've already digged through the documentation and it seems that javascript API/DOM is not exposing anything that could be used to disable color correction.

Comment: There is no API for the use case as your approach to solve the problem comes from the wrong perspective. If images have color correction information then the information should be used when rendering the image. Remove the color correction information from the image file and the problem is gone. I suggest you reconsider your orignal problem, as you don't state why you need to go through this in the first place.

Comment: Mikko, from my persepctive, all gamma and ICC information are "metadata" which may be used for display, but should not be used for non-display purposes. Unfortunately, the specification (in my understanding of that gibberish) demands that no matter how the image is painted (in <img> tag, on canvas, etc.), it should look the same. So if we have no color correction metadata in ImageData object, the only possibility to make that imagedata painted in the same way as the original image is to have imagedata already contain modified colors :[ Eh, too bad. I will modify my images.